# How to pass byte[] data and get response from client?

Tags: c#, .net, httpresponse

I have image in the form of byte[] data and code to pass byte data  to get response from client. I need help in putting them together

I tried to use the code where I have my byte data but the async operations created a lot of confusion

"data" contains the byte[] data

```cs
  private async void InitializeVideoFeedModule()
        {
            //Must in UI thread
            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
            {
                //Raw data and decoded data listener
                if (videoParser == null)
                {
                    videoParser = new DJIVideoParser.Parser();
                    videoParser.Initialize( delegate (byte[] data)
                    {
                        return DJISDKManager.Instance.VideoFeeder.ParseAssitantDecodingInfo(0, data);

                    });
                }
             }
         }
```

code to pass byte data and get response

```cs
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Prediction-Key", "XXXXX");

// Prediction URL - replace this example URL with valid Prediction URL.
string sequenceURL = "https://abc/dcr/xyz";
HttpResponseMessage response;

using (var content = new ByteArrayContent(data))
{
   content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
   response = await client.PostAsync(sequenceURL, content);
  var output = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
   Console.WriteLine(output);

   JObject json = JObject.Parse(output);

}
```

The delegate object and async operations are causing conflicts when I use them together.

Comment: Are you wanting to send it as a byte array, a stream, or something different?

Comment: @MitchWilkins I’m trying to send it as a byte array

Comment: can you post the errors you're getting?

Comment: You want to run an async delegate that doesn’t make use of await and have it run in the UI thread?  I don’t see that you’re getting any benefit from the async/await pattern by doing this...

Comment: @joehoper my end result it to pass the data and get the response. I got the byte[] data from a sample code which I am sending to client. I you think there is a different way to achieve this please let me know